# Send image path to database

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0

I use this code for uploading image to the server.YES its working.but i need to send a image path to my database.I have a database with Profiles table and ImagePath field there.

How can i do this...

My working code is here

```
public partial class ProfileDetails2 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intFileSizeLimit = 10;
    string strFileNameWithPath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string strExtensionName = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strFileNameWithPath);
    string strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileNameWithPath);
    int intFileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength / 1024;


    strExtensionName = strExtensionName.ToLower();
    if (strExtensionName.Equals(".jpg") || strExtensionName.Equals(".gif"))
    {

        if (intFileSize < intFileSizeLimit)
        {

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + "img" + strExtensionName);

            lblMessage.Text = "Uploaded file details <hr />" +
                "File path on your Computer: " + strFileNameWithPath + "<br />" +
                "File Name: " + strFileName + "<br />" +
                "File Extension Name: " + strExtensionName + "<br />" +
                "File Size: " + intFileSize.ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "File size exceeded than limit " + intFileSizeLimit + " KB, Please upload smaller file.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Only .jpg or .gif file are allowed, try again!";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What, if the extension is ".JPG"?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the path using

```
string strFileNameWithPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Uploads\" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

This will give you the full path inside the application root path.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh this is so unsafe. The path might contain "\..\"!

Comment: @DnshPly i need to send this path to Database field.how can i do it ?

Comment: In ideal case i don't think it is unsafe because Request.PhysicalApplicationPath returns the full path to the current directory (eg. C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WebAppName\) and Uploads is the folder you use to uploads the files in and then append the filename of the Posted file which cannot contain '..' as it is not allowed. Maybe if using other tools like fiddler, firebug, i can't say but i think will be safe in those cases as well.

Comment: I suppose you have some code to insert the data from the page to the database (an insert procedure maybe). You have one!! right???

Comment: Ohh..Ideally you must create a Data Access Layer for doing database operations that contains methods which defines generic methods to perform database operations between database and application. Have a look at the link http://aspdotnetcode.blogspot.in/2010/09/insert-record-in-database-using-stored.html  You can find better code but this is a good starting point. Try it and you will be good to go. After doing this I would also encourage you to look at DataAccessBlock of Microsoft Enterprise Library.